# ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback not being hit

Tags: c#, servicepointmanager

I have the following code.

```
public void Submit(string XML)
{
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateCertificate;
TestWS.CW serv = new TestWS.CW();
string s = serv.Check(XML);
}

private static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
return true;
}
```

However the code never enters the `ValidateCertificate` method.... It does if I submit a standard `HttpsWebRequest` but if I use a webservice it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even If it does, your `ValidateCertificate` method return always `true` .

Comment: I know, it is supposed to always return true.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Stick this in your startup code for your HTTP processing somewhere...

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

That does it for me, but I only do THIS for debug builds...